# Assign acceptable input based on a previous input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Guees the Number</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="header"> Guess the number</h1>
        <h3 class="info">Select your difficulty below</h3>
        <small>You have 10 guesses</small>
        <div class="settings">
            <div class="easy">
                <h1>Easy Mode</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="normal">
                <h1>Normal Mode</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="hard">
                <h1>Hard Mode</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="master">
                <h1>Master Mode</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    <form action="" class="myForm">
    <input type="text" class="guess" placeholder="Enter your Guess here!">
    <input class="submit" vlaue="submit" type="submit"></input>
```

I'm making guessing games where the user can choose a difficulty mode that then changes the range of the random number generator ie( 0 to 25 0 to 50 etc.)
Below is my attempt using if statements

<

```
easy.addEventListener('click', easyActive) // These are the difficulties
function easyActive() {
    easy.classList.add('active')
    normal.classList.remove('active')
    hard.classList.remove('active')
    master.classList.remove('active')
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.className = "para"
    p.innerText = 'Easy mode sets the range from 0 to 25'
    easy.append(p)
    if(p.innerText === 'Easy mode sets the range from 0 to 25') {
    random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)  
    }
}

normal.addEventListener('click', normalActive)
function normalActive() {
    easy.classList.remove('active')
    normal.classList.add('active')
    hard.classList.remove('active')
    master.classList.remove('active')
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.className = "para"
    p.innerText = 'Normal mode sets the range from 0 to 50'
    normal.append(p)
    if(p.innerText === 'Normal mode sets the range from 0 to 50') {
        random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 51)      
    }
}

hard.addEventListener('click', hardActive)
function hardActive() {
    easy.classList.remove('active')
    normal.classList.remove('active')
    hard.classList.add('active')
    master.classList.remove('active')
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.className = "para"
    p.innerText = 'Hard mode sets the range from 0 to 100'
    hard.append(p)
    if(p.innerText === 'Hard mode sets the range from 0 to 100') {
        random =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)      
    }
}

master.addEventListener('click', masterActive) 
function masterActive() {
    easy.classList.remove('active')
    normal.classList.remove('active')
    hard.classList.remove('active')
    master.classList.add('active')
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.className = "para"
    p.innerText = "Master mode sets the range from 0 to 200"
    master.append(p)
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 201)
}

myForm.addEventListener('submit', click)

function click(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     const ul = document.querySelector('.guesses') // This is what i tried to do
     if(easy.className  == "active") {
         if(guess.value > 25 || guess.value < 0 || isNaN(guess.value)) {
           alert("Please Enter a Number between 0 and 25")
    }
  } else if(normal.className == "active") {
      if(guess.value > 50 || guess.value < 0 || isNaN(guess.value)) {
           alert("Please Enter a Number between 0 and 50")
    }
   } else if(hard.className == "active") {
       if(guess.value > 100 || guess.value < 0 || isNaN(guess.value)) {
           alert("Please Enter a number between 0 and 100")
    }
   } else if(master.className == "active") {
       if(guess.value > 200 || guess.value < 0 || isNaN(guess.value)) {
        alert("Please Enter a number between 0 and 200")
   }
 } else {
 
 // The rest is just the guessing game
```

. I want to make it so that when the user inputs their guess that it only accepts an input that is between the range of the difficulty chosen

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the HTML too

Comment: I suggest you to create an object and store it in a variable, in which you associate each difficulty with the range limit, something like this: `let limits = { easy: 25, normal: 50, hard: 100}`. Then you can lookup the values from there in your functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fully functional snippet demonstrates what "DRY" (don't repeat yourself) really means. There are a number of points where repetition was avoided:

- The quiz modes are defined in terms of an object (here:`maxN`). The magic then develops from there:
- Part of the the HTML (selection of quiz mode) is generated by `map()`-ping over the keys of `maxN`.
- Then, in the `stgs.onclick`function the actions to follow on any click on the four `<input>` elements in `div.settings` are defined - but only when an element `el` with `el.tagName==="INPUT"` is clicked on, will they unfold:

  - determine the upper boundary of the guessing range (`mx=maxN[el.value]`) for the chosen quiz mode (`el.value`),
  - set the `guess.max=mx` attribute for the input field receiving the guesses
  - delete any `.textContent` that might be found in `resp`
  - and generate a random `number` in the range of `0 ... mx`
- *Hint:* `~~()` is a shorthand way of doing `Math.floor()`:
  `~` is
  actually the "bitwise negation operator" that implictly applies a
  `Math.floor()` on the operand. By applying it *twice* the negation
  is reversed again.

The event handler for the `form.submit` event compares the guessed with the generated secret number and writes appropriate hints into `#response`.

I also chose to replace your four "mode" divs by radio buttons. These can be formatted through CSS in any way you like. Radio buttons have the built-in ability to allow only one of the same-name elements to be checked. So you won't have to take care of that in your JavaScript part.

**DRY** makes it easy to maintain your code, as you can see in the above example: In order to include the extra level "fiendish" I only need to add the extra property `fiendish:500` to the `maxN` object and everything else falls into place!

By wrapping the whole thing in an "IIFE" all "global" constants and variables like `number` or the DOM-element references `rng`, `stgs` etc. are encapsulated in a temporary scope. This makes it harder for users to look for the "secret" number and it also keeps your global scope clean for further scripting operations.

```js
(D => { // IIFE (immediately invoced functional expression) keeping the global scope "clean"
  // the following "destructing assignment" will assign DOM element references
  // to the four constants rng, resp, guess and stgs. D is just an alias for document.
  // .map() will take each of the strings in the array ["#range","#response",...] 
  // and use them as selectors in D.querySelector() calls returning 
  // the appropriate DOM element references.
  const [rng, resp, guess, stgs] = ["#range", "#response", ".guess", ".settings"]
  .map(el => D.querySelector(el)),

  // The object maxN has one property for each quiz level. 
  // Each key is the name of a level and the associated value 
  // is the upper limit of its number range.
    maxN = {
      easy: 25,
      normal: 50,
      hard: 100,
      master: 200,
      fiendish: 500
    };
  // the secret number to be guessed is in "global scope" within the IIFE
  var number;

  // generate the html-string to represent the radio buttons (with labels)
  // for the different quiz level's and assign it
  // to stgs.innerHTML:
  stgs.innerHTML = Object.keys(maxN).map(k =>
    `<label><input type="radio" name="level" value="${k}"> 
     ${k[0].toUpperCase()+k.slice(1)} Mode </label>`).join("");

  // define the onclick event handler for the #settings div:
  stgs.onclick = function(ev) {
    const el = ev.target; // el is the element that was clicked

    // Return without doing anything, if the event was NOT
    // triggered by a click on an <input> element.
    // (a click on a <label> element will implicitly
    // trigger a click event on the enclosed <input> element) 
    if (el.tagName !== "INPUT") return;

    // Ok, a quiz level was selected. Step into action:
 
   // reformat the labels: (go through all children of #settings and
    // set add/remove the class "selected" depending on whether 
    // the label has a checked input item in it or not)
    [...stgs.children].forEach(la=>
      la.classList.toggle("selected",la.querySelector("input:checked")));
    // get the upper limit of the number range: mx
    const mx = maxN[el.value];
    // set the upper limit for the number input field:
    guess.max = mx;
    // clear any text from the resp element:
    resp.textContent = "";
    // display the current number range:
    rng.textContent = `(0...${mx})`;
    // calculate the "secret" number:
    number = ~~(Math.random() * (mx + 1));
  }

  D.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let r = guess.value - number;
    resp.textContent = !r ? "You nailed it!" : r > 0 ? "No - Go lower." : "Not yet - you need to aim higher"
  })
})(document) // end of IIFE
```

```css
label {
  display: block
}

.guess {
  width: 200px
}
[type=radio] {display:none}
.selected {font-weight:900;color:red}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="header"> Guess the number</h1>
  <h3 class="info">Select your difficulty below</h3>
  <div class="settings"></div><br>
  <small>You have 10 guesses <span id="range"></span></small>
  <form action="" class="myForm">
    <input type="number" class="guess" placeholder="Enter your Guess here!" min="0">
    <input class="submit" value="submit" type="submit">
  </form>
  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am going to be honest I am still quite new to JS and don't really understand most of what you have done here. Do you mind maybe explaining it or doing it in a simpler way?

Comment: Fair point - I _did_ kind of overload the answer a little bit. I will try and insert a few more comments into the code.

Comment: Have another look at the comments. There are a lot of details to take in. After all, it is a "complete page" now.